# Xbox 360 Network Communications

Tags: networking, xbox

So I read in another thread that:

> ...the Xbox is a closed system. Forget any direct TCP/IP interaction, you can only communicate with other consoles present in the Xbox Live! network, and you can't do raw HTTP connections.

This makes me curious as to how an app like Last.fm for Xbox LIVE works.  I would think it would require network communications with Last.fm servers, for user identification and for receiving audio streams.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Either MS or CBS are running an XLSP farm and proxying all the traffic to the Last API.

Comment: Which would explain why we are being charged a premium for this content now.

Comment: Ditto on Netflix, I shudder to think of how complex that system must be on the server end.

Comment: Where do I find my information on XLSP ... APIs, architecture, etc.?  Is it necessary to join a developer program to get full documenation?  Thanks.

Comment: You need to have an Xbox contract to get any of the XDK docs, but you can sign up for the XNA CC which uses the same underlying system (does cost $99/year if you want to deploy to an Xbox though).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little unclear as to what's required. If I sign up for the XNA CC, would I be able to build a prototype Xbox app which could communicate with my own server code running on XLSP?  Thanks.

Comment: No, you need to be a Real Developer, the kind that pays MS thousands of dollars. XNA is only allowed to talk (over Live) to other Xboxes.

Comment: To clarify, you need to be Real Developer to use the XLSP servers. But via XNA you can develop an Xbox game that uses Live to talk to other Xboxes.

Comment: My employer is asking me to prototype an Xbox app which exchanges information with our own servers.  My understanding (from this thread) is that I would need to write XLSP code which would act as a proxy between Xboxes and our own servers.  This requires being a "Real Developer"?  How does this process get started?  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not really sure, the higherups negotiate those contracts. If you have a relationship with a large publisher (EA, Activision, Ubisoft, etc) that would probably be a place to start. My email is in my profile if you have more detailed questions but this is starting to stray into NDA territory.

Answer (score 1):

The Xbox 360 is certainly capable of making connections to any remote host just as your personal computer does, however, as a security measure, it is likely that Microsoft requires you to be an official Xbox licensed developer to do this. In addition to this, official Xbox titles are required to go through stringent validation to ensure a secure system.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. A production Xbox can only connect through XLSP gateway servers. A devkit can open arbitrary sockets, not sure if that is what you were getting at.

Comment: The system is technically capable of connecting to any remote location (think of homebrew applications), but official licensed titles are likely required to use secure connections to Microsoft servers.

Comment: They don't need to be MS servers, anyone (well, any licensed Xbox developer) can run their own XLSP gateway. It is exceedingly painful though, so fewer and fewer people are going that route.

Comment: Does MS have any requirements regarding the networking protocol or security between the XLSP server and the developer's own content server?

Comment: Also (somewhat unrelated), is it possible to prototype an Xbox app on Windows, communicating with an XLSP server?

Comment: I don't remember anything in particular about protocols beyond the gateway, most of their limitations are content-related, not about security. Not sure on the second question, pretty sure we didn't but that doesn't mean you can't. Not sure why you would ever need to :-)